# Unable to create core [new_core] Caused by: null in apache solr 8.2.0 on centos 7

Tags: solr, centos7

I installed apache solr on CentOS 7 to follow this link https://computingforgeeks.com/install-apache-solr-on-centos-fedora/

After Completing installation, solr status is

[image]

After running this command

```
sudo systemctl enable solr
```

Show below message

```
solr.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig solr on
```

I ran the command to create testcollection.

```
sudo su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c testcollection -n data_driven_schema_configs"
```

After running the command, error is showing below

```
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'testcollection': Unable to create core [tpcollection3] Caused by: null
```

Can I get any suggestion for creating collection or core successfully.
Question are

```
1. Why cannot enable solr on centos 7?
2. Why cannot create collection or core?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved to follow another way.

You can extract your desired directory. I made a directory /solr

```
mkdir /solr
```

Download latest version solr from  latest [release of Apache Solr](https://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/)

Extract it

```
tar -xvf solr-8.2.0.tgz
```

Add a User

```
useradd solr
```

Give permission

```
chown -R solr:solr solr-8.2.0
```

Go to your created user

```
su - solr
```

Go to Extracted solr bin file

```
 cd solr-8.2.0/bin
```

Start Solr, check solr status and create solr core Or collection

```
./solr start  
./solr status
./solr create -c testcollection -n data_driven_schema_configs
```

You will see your created collection or core successful message.

```
Created new core 'testcollection'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `/sbin/chkconfig solr on` is a command fallback to `systemctl enable solr`, it achieves the same task that is to enable Solr at startup. That said, there is a [service installation script](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/taking-solr-to-production.html#service-installation-script) that should help install Solr as a service : `/opt/solr/bin/install_solr_service.sh`.
2. Ensure you have set the right permissions on Solr directories and restart Solr, also I don't think you need the `sudo su` part :

   ```
   chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/
   ./solr restart
   ./solr create -c testcollection
   ```

Comment: I installed solr  and import data from mysql successfully in ubuntu 19.04. In CentOS 7 it is does not work. I followed according to your answer. But it does not work.

Comment: Did you try as root ? You may also need to set the server path when restarting : `/opt/solr/bin/solr restart -s /opt/solr/server/solr/`.